# Change wordpress menu href

Tags: wordpress, menu, href

I wanna change the href of a specific menu item on all pages. Is this possible? Where should I put the code?

I also added this javascript to the end of a specific page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("menu-item-100").href="xyz.php"; 
</script>
```

It didn't work even though when I viewed the page source it showed that the script was placed after the original href of the menu.
I don't wanna use custom links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting this in your footer.php

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("#menu-item-100").attr("href", new_href);
});
</script>
```

Wordpress a lot of the times needs to have `jQuery(document).ready(function($)` for no-conflict reasons.

Comment: This is way better than the javascript version; since it can extend waaaay easier for longer nested elements. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try it, may be helpful to you:

```
$("#menu-item-100").attr("href", new_href);
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the element with the ID of `menu-item-100` had an `a` tag inside of it; so I had to retarget the whole thing.

This fixed the whole thing.

```
document.getElementById('menu-item-100').getElementsByTagName('a')[0].href="THE LINK";
```

Thanks to @NooBskie I put it inside the `footer.php` and it affected all the pages.

Comment: A shorter way you could use if your using jquery is to just do `$("#menu-item-100 a").attr("href", new_href);`

Comment: @NooBskie I don't know why the jquery version you provided, didn't work. I even changed the double-quotations to single ones and it still didn't work. The javascript worked fine though. This is the code that didn't work:     $("#menu-item-100 a").attr("href", "http://google.com");

Comment: @NooBskie No, it just kept the old href.

Comment: @NooBskie How stupid of me; I had forgotten to put it inside a function. Now it works perfectly! Thanks! 

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("#menu-item-100 a").attr("href", "#");
});

Comment: Im not 100% sure then i'm working on my WordPress site and the same code is working for me

Comment: Awesome glad to help accept the answer if it helped please:D